# Total CPU usage and CPU usage under processes list is different in FreeBSD top implementation?

Tags: freebsd, cpu, top

For some reason, overall CPU usage on my FreeBSD machine fluctuates between 1% and 85%, but the CPU usage in processes column never adds up to this amount. For example here the overall CPU usage is 83.5%, but CPU usage in processes list is less than 2%:

```
last pid: 22965;  load averages:  1.45,  1.72,  3.06                                                                                                                                                                                                  up 151+20:08:57 12:32:38
137 processes: 2 running, 135 sleeping
CPU: 83.5% user,  0.0% nice, 12.8% system,  0.0% interrupt,  3.8% idle
Mem: 222M Active, 88M Inact, 315M Wired, 16M Cache, 110M Buf, 342M Free
Swap: 1996M Total, 30M Used, 1966M Free, 1% Inuse

  PID USERNAME    THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE    TIME    CPU COMMAND
22965 martin       1  96    0  7704K  4172K RUN      0:00  1.27% snmpset
 1234 root          1  44    0  3804K  1068K select  50:36  0.00% hald-addon-storage
 1204 haldaemon     1  44    0  7236K  2300K select  24:13  0.00% hald
 1135 root          1  44    0  3372K   928K nanslp   9:34  0.00% cron
46828 martin       1  44    0 11844K  4140K select   6:06  0.00% irssi
  407 _pflogd       1  44    0  3528K   604K bpf      5:41  0.00% pflogd
86984 root          1  44    0  5284K   996K select   5:14  0.00% gam_server
95843 martin       1  76    0  4560K  1192K wait     5:03  0.00% bash
 6714 martin       1  44    0  5748K  2512K select   4:46  0.00% screen
  775 root          1  44    0  3344K   532K select   3:48  0.00% syslogd
```

How are those two `CPU` fields different? What might cause such behavior? The machine definitely responds slower at the times when the total CPU usage is around 60 - 80%.

**EDIT:**

Output of `top` if kernel threads are also shown(`Shift + s`):

```
last pid: 54866;  load averages:  0.62,  0.90,  1.02                                                                                                                                                                                                  up 153+19:26:17 11:49:58
208 processes: 3 running, 188 sleeping, 17 waiting
CPU: 75.3% user,  0.0% nice, 12.4% system,  0.0% interrupt, 12.4% idle
Mem: 395M Active, 154M Inact, 324M Wired, 16M Cache, 110M Buf, 94M Free
Swap: 1996M Total, 112M Used, 1883M Free, 5% Inuse, 8K In

  PID USERNAME    THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE    TIME    CPU COMMAND
   11 root          1 171 ki31     0K     8K RUN    2809.4 52.78% idle
54866 martin       1  96    0  6680K  3548K RUN      0:00  0.98% snmpset
15836 root          1  44    0   322M   307M select  31:51  0.29% Xorg
   12 root         17 -60    -     0K   136K WAIT   455:55  0.00% intr
   17 root          1  44    -     0K     8K syncer 162:57  0.00% syncer
 1234 root          1  44    0  3804K  1068K select  51:16  0.00% hald-addon-storage
    3 root          1  -8    -     0K     8K -       27:06  0.00% g_up
 1204 haldaemon     1  44    0  7236K  2268K select  24:32  0.00% hald
    4 root          1  -8    -     0K     8K -       23:52  0.00% g_down
   13 root          1 -16    -     0K     8K -       20:20  0.00% yarrow
   14 root         20 -64    -     0K   160K -       14:37  0.00% usb
    2 root          1  -8    -     0K     8K -       10:42  0.00% g_event
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `top` only displays *user* processes (i.e. processes other than the kernel and its threads). It's possible that the kernel is busy with disk or network IO that is not showing up in `top`'s display. You can toggle the display of kernel threads in `top` by pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>.

You can use the `vmstat` utility to display statistics about (among other things) network and disk activity since the system started. `vmstat -i` will show the number of interrupts received by each device since start up, and the average rate per second at which they were received. Use `vmstat -p da` to see what your disks are doing.

Other tools like `iostat`, `systat` and `netstat` may also prove informative.

You can increase the responsiveness of your system under load by tweaking the scheduler config. To change it now, run `sysctl kern.sched.preempt_thresh=240` as root. To have the same settings apply at boot, make sure you add it to `/etc/sysctl.conf` as well. This should help, but note that its effectiveness will be limited by your workload, and characteristics of the hardware.

Comment: Thanks! As this machine handles fairly lot of network traffic, then this might indeed cause the high CPU usage. Am I correct that each network packet will cause an interrupt to CPU? If yes, how can I see those because even with `Shift + s` in `top`, the CPU utilization of all the processes in CPU column is very low while the overall CPU usage is high. I updated the original post with another `top` output with kernel threads shown and where the overall CPU usage is 75.3%, but CPU usage in processes list is less than 2%.

Comment: You can try tools like `systat`, `tcpdump` and `netstat` to get an idea of network load. `vmstat -i` will show what's generating interrupts, and might be a good place to start.

Comment: But still, how are the CPU utilization in `top` header different from CPU utilization in CPU column?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know without digging through the `top` source. It's probably to do with sample intervals, but that's just a guess.